# Black screen at boot [SOLVED]

Tags: release-loki, boot, dual-boot, thinkpad

I updated eOS and the AppCenter told me to restart. I had uninstalled some applications prior to running the update.

Now I only get a black screen after the eOS logo splash screen during bootup. When I force shutdown using the power key, I see the eOS logo again.

Did I uninstall critical applications? I don't remember what I uninstalled. How can I fix this?

Also, if I select the following from the grub menu:

Advanced Options for elementary -> linux kernel 4.4.0-81(recovery) -> resume normal boot

It boots up fine and I can login but the performance is sluggish. Everything lags.

Please help.

Comment: reinstall the OS, trying to fix that problem is something really really hard. you are not giving us any detail or clue, this forum doesnt do black magic, so just reinstall it

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try to figure it out, if nothing works I'll reinstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything works again! No need to reinstall!

I pressed `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to boot into tty1 and the $DISPLAY environment variable was empty.

So redefined the DISPLAY variable using `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and rebooted. That's it.

P.S. IIRC, I may have uninstalled UXTerm before the running the update.