# How to restore elementary boot logo in grub file

Tags: release-juno, boot, grub, logo

I need to reenable the splash logo in the

> /etc/default/grub

file. I needed to boot in verbose mode to fix a slow boot issue but foolishly didn't backup the grub file so now don't have the elementarry logo at boot.

Can someone please post their grub file so that I can restore the logo? I tried setting quiet splash and ran

> sudo update-grub

but there is still no boot logo.

```
Current grub file.
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 2):

The elementary logo comes from the plymouth. Plymouth has different themes and it looks like you have changed the theme. In order to return to the elementary theme you have to type into terminal

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

and type the number of the /usr/share/plymouth/themes/elementary/elementary.plymouth theme in your list.
after this

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

in order to update initramfs with the selected new theme.

Another reason is the $DISPLAY environment variable, you can check the solution in this answer - [Black screen at boot [SOLVED]](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12470/black-screen-at-boot-solved)

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what you mean by 'and type the number of the /usr/share/plymouth/themes/elementary/elementary.plymouth theme in your list'. Which list?? I haven't directly edited the plymouth theme.

Comment: The first line of my answer is a tool to select the default plymouth theme. It happens sometimes when you mess with the grub that the theme is changed. With this tool you can change it to any one you want. But first of all, do you have any logo (like the ubuntu one) during the boot or you just have a black screen until the greeter is loaded?

Comment: Just a black screen until the login box (greeter?) appears

Comment: Out put from config command: There is only one alternative in link group default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth): /usr/share/plymouth/themes/elementary/elementary.plymouth
Nothing to configure.

Comment: It looks like that your plymouth theme is not changed. So when the login box (so called pantheon greeter in eOS) appears, can you press  Ctrl+Alt+F1 to go into console login, type your credentials and when you log in - type `echo $DISPLAY` and press enter ? Share what you receive after typing it. To return back to the graphical login press Ctrl+Alt+F7 after you do the above.

Comment: it just displays a blank line. When I shutdown / restart I do get the logo during shutdown. I think I'll just reinstall at some point as on a fresh install this was working. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: if the result is blank line it means that the DISPLAY variable is not initialized. Before you reinstall I can suggest you to type again into console login `export DISPLAY=":0.0"` and reboot to see if it changes as suggested in https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12470/black-screen-at-boot-solved