# How to quit Debian Logo on Startup, after install Gnome-Shell

Tags: boot, logo

I installed Gnome Shell and the i uninstalled... All is fine but when Start the computer it shows an image that says "Debian 8", then Show a animation of Elementary, before the Login Screen. I want to quit that image of Debian.

I try this [How to restore elementary boot logo in grub file](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21067/how-to-restore-elementary-boot-logo-in-grub-file) and did not work... What can i do?

Sorry for my bad English, i am for El Salvador, CA.

Edit: I understand that Plymouth Themes change the animation during eos is charging right? Well... That it's fine. But before that, show the image. I don't have other so installed, so don't show me the grub menu, only that image... Maybe with make menuconfig? But I'm afraid to touch the kernel and break my system.